# Sudo and Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, sudo

If I call a bash script with `sudo`, for example:

`sudo bash script.sh`

Do I still have to use `sudo` inside the script in cases like this:

`sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Course. I am getting a strange error: "+ sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/apt-fast =>> cleanstart.sh: line 134: sudo: command not found" that's why I did this basic question.

Comment: That's odd.  The error message seems to indicate that `sudo` can't find the `chmod` command.  Unless the command in the script is `sudo "chmod +x /usr/bin/apt-fast"`, which would cause `sudo` to look for a command named `"chmod +x /usr/bin/apt-fast"`.  (But in any case, you don't need `sudo` inside the script.)

Comment: I see from [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002333/bash-wget-and-mv-command-not-found) that your script had clobbered `$PATH`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  the command will be run with root privileges and all commands that the script runs will inherit the privileges.

Answer (score -1):

no, by calling sudo you are running a process in kernal mode which means you have access to everything, you no longer have to use special permissions in different areas of your code/script.

Comment: You're not running in any sort of "kernel mode". You're just running it as a user with elevated permissions.